# How to Add Every n,2n,3n.. character to a string in Java

Tags: java, string

I am newbie to Java, I am trying to write a function which  Returns a string that consists of all and only the characters in positions n, 2n, 3n, and so on in the current string

I tried following code and it didnt work

```
public String everyNth(String str, int n) {
String result="";
(i=0; i<str.length(); i=i+n){
result+=str.charAt(i);
}
return result;
}
```

Please help me with my mistakes

Answer (score 1):

One option here is to iterate over every character in the input string, and retain a character if it be a multiple of `n`:

```
public String everyNth(String str, int n) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder("");

    if (n == 1) {
        result.append(str.charAt(0));
    }
    for (int i=1; i < str.length(); ++i) {
        if ((i + 1) % n == 0) {
            result.append(str.charAt(i));
        }
    }

    return result.toString()
}
```

**Usage:**

```
String result = everyNth("1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", 1);
System.out.println(result);
result = everyNth("1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", 3);
System.out.println(result);
```

**Output:**

```
1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
369behknqtwz
```

Comment: ,Thank you so much for reply

Comment: In Output we should not get 1 because nth character needs to be first

Comment: @studentsiva I updated my answer per your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

According to your discussion with Tim. I have modified the code.Besides that, your code has compilation error in java language scenario.

1, Miss `for` keyword.

2, Miss `int` keyword for variable i.

You should use IDE like Eclipse so that any compilation error can be shown before you run the code.

Please refer to code below.

```
 public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Test test = new Test();
        String result = test.everyNth("hello world", 2);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    public String everyNth(String str, int n) {
        String result = "";
        for (int i = n - 1; i < str.length(); i = i + n) {
            result += str.charAt(i);
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, I am not able to get expected output

Comment: @studentsiva Please give me an example of how it can't work.